# NDK isn't linking my lib*.so file to java

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So, I am working on an Android NDK project and I have gotten my C++ code to compile into a `.so` file with the help of an `Android.mk` make file. It even assembles, but won't run in the emulator. I keep getting this error:

```
06-22 17:01:06.374 2463-2463/com.example.SanAngeles E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.SanAngeles, PID: 2463
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsanangeles.so"
```

And here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Project
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := sanangeles

FREETYPE_INCLUDE := freetype2-android/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
 $(FREETYPE_INCLUDE) \
 $(FREETYPE_INCLUDE)/freetype/ \
 $(FREETYPE_INCLUDE)/freetype/config \
 $(FREETYPE_INCLUDE)/freetype/internal \
 $(FREETYPE_INCLUDE)/freetype/internal/services
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    src/triangle.cpp \
    src/app-android.c \
    src/Helpers/ivec2.cpp \
    src/Helpers/vec3.cpp \
    src/Renderers/BoxRenderer.cpp \
    src/Renderers/TextRenderer.cpp \
    src/Renderers/Shader.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Edit: Forgot to include project structure

```
app/
    build/
    src/
        main/
            java/
            jni/
                freetype2-android/
                src/
                Android.mk
                Application.mk
    build.gradle
build
build.gradle
```

Edit2:

Where it is loaded in Java:

app/src/main/java/com.example.SanAngeles/DemoActivity.java

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLView = new DemoGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sanangeles");
    }
}
```

Edit 3:

build.gradle in app/

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = 'com.example.SanAngeles'
        minSdkVersion    = 4
        targetSdkVersion = 23
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/libs']
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled=false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which directory does your built *.so end up in? Does it depend on any other *.so? Can you include where you load the *.so in Java?

Comment: It doesn't depend on any other *.so files, just one *.a file. The *.so files end up in the respective app/src/main/jni/libs folders (there is a folder for each architecture). And here is where it is loaded in Java (this project is modified from Google's San-Angeles ndk example).

Comment: The *.apk file is just a *.zip file; rename it and have a look to see if the build process has packaged your *.so into it.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. It isn't in the main folder or any subdirectories.

Comment: How do I get it to be included in the apk? I'm already using `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`, shouldn't that be enough?